# Saving style in tabulator mutator

Tags: tabulator

I am using JSON where each cell data is a JSON object containing a "value" to be displayed and an optional "style" to apply to the cell. I initially used a mutator to change object to only be the value, but I lost the optional style. Is there a way to save the style, so it would be there for a formatter to use later?

Currently I am use custom accessors, sorters and formatters. This works, but I feel like I am rewritting lots of functionality built into tabulator. Next I will need to write custom editors. Seems like there has to be a better way?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to properly ask questions in order to get an answer that is relevant to you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a custom `formatter` for that cell column.  In the formatter method, you can then return HTML where the value is wrapped in an element with the applied style.

Comment: As I stated I am already using a custom formater. I am looking for a better way so I also don't have to also write custom accessors, sorters, editors...

Comment: Built-in functionalities assume cell values are basic types.  To get the functionality you want with your current data structure, you would have to rewrite them to explicitly tell Tabulator how to handle it.  Can you alter your data object before passing it to Tabulator?  If so, add new properties for value and style, bind a column to value so sorting, filtering, editors, etc. act on that; then in your formatter, you can access the entire row data and extract the style from it, then build and return the HTML string you want to display.

Some example code and restrictions may help.